# How much is "\377\377\377\377\020\020\006" in Hex?

Tags: c

How much is `"\377\377\377\377\020\020\006"` in Hex? What does `"\"` mean here? I know `"0x"` represents Hexadecimal

Comment: Those are *octal* (base 8) numbers.

Comment: Where did you get them from?

Comment: ..or an ASCII string

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg yes you're right!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a sequence of seven bytes in octal, i.e. base-8, notation. In binary they would look like this (spaces are for clarity)

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 00010000 00010000 00000110
```

Translated to HEX this would be

```
      FF       FF       FF       FF       10       10       06
```

Since this is a string literal, it has a null terminator at the end, so the complete sequence of bytes that it represents is `FF FF FF FF 10 10 06 00`.

Octals are very easy to translate to binary, because all you need to remember is an eight-element table below:

```
0 - 000
1 - 001
2 - 010
3 - 011
4 - 100
5 - 101
6 - 110
7 - 111
```

The conversion is a mechanical substitution of digits in base-8 with three-bit sequences from the table.

Comment: @chux You are right, there's null terminator at the end! Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`"\377\377\377\377\020\020\006"` is a string with octal constants.  The `\` is the start of an escape sequence, and if a valid octal digit follows then that digit plus up to two more that follow indicate that the next bytes it denoted by the given octal code.

From the section 6.4.4.4 of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> octal-escape-sequence:
>    \ octal-digit
>    \ octal-digit  octal-digit
>    \ octal-digit  octal-digit  octal-digit
>
> ...
>
> The octal digits that follow the backslash in an octal escape sequence
>   are taken to be part of  the  construction  of  a  single  character 
>   for  an  integer  character  constant  or  of  a  single wide
>   character for a wide character constant.  The numerical value of the
>   octal integer so formed specifies the value of the desired character
>   or wide character.

Taking the octal:

```
377 377 377 377 020 020 006
```

And converting it to binary:

```
11 111 111  11 111 111  11 111 111  11 111 111  00 010 000  00 010 000  00 000 110
 1111 1111   1111 1111   1111 1111   1111 1111   0001 0000   0001 0000   0000 0110
```

Gives us the following hex:

```
FF FF FF FF 10 10 06
```

So you could also define the above string with hex escape sequences as:

```
"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x10\x10\x06"
```

Also note that because this is a string constant, there is additionally a null byte at the end, so there are a total of 8 bytes.